# XElement exists and Value in XElement is not Null

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have to parse a big Xml data. Below is small example of my Xml Data

```
<Orders>
 <PersonalData>
   <Id>1</Id>
   <WhoOrderedName>
       <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
       <MiddleName/>
       <LastName>xyz</LastName>
   </WhoOderedName>
 </PersonalData>
   .....
</Orders>
```

I have to verify each element exists and if the value is not null. For now i am able to achieve it in this way but is there any better way to verify elements exists and value not null. Below is my code

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmldata)
if (xml.Descendants("PersonalData").Elements("Id").Any())
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(xml.Descendants("PersonalData").Elements("Id").First().Value))
        OrdersXml += xml.Descendants("PersonalData").Elements("Id").First(); //adding the XElement to another xml string
    else
       Errordetails += "\r\n Id is Null";
}
else
   Errordetails += "\r\n Id element is required";
```

Comment: verify each element exists.. : which element?

Comment: @greenfeet: Xelement like <Id> and <FirstName>

Comment: Define all mandatory (and optional?) elements and valid element contents in an xml schema (XSD) and validate the XML against that XSD? -- see [How to: Validate Using XSD (LINQ to XML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb387037.aspx)

Comment: I only see you checking if the <Id> element exists, not <FirstName>. You can check that every <PersonalData> element has a <Id>, <FirstName>, <MiddleName> and <LastName> using a schema

Comment: @greenfeet: the code i have above is just an small bit of my whole code, but i do have firstname and lastname and all element verification process in my code.

Comment: @Corak: I am already doing that. this is for Optional elements only, Example: In my mandatory elements if data changes like i have element <IDtype> it has allowed values as drivers Lic # , ssn, Dob. If the IDtype value is ssn# i dont not require firstname element and last name element. but if value is Driver License i do require Firstname and lastname elements.  again this just one element i am talking about here but i do have lot of elements which has do be done similar way based on the mandatory elements value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, approach below takes slightly less code and it doesn't queries the element from xml each time (unlike your approach):

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmldata)

var id = xml.Descendants("PersonalData").Elements("Id").FirstOrDefault();
if (id != null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id.Value))
        OrdersXml += id;
    else
       Errordetails += "\r\n Id is Null";
}
else
   Errordetails += "\r\n Id element is required";
```

Comment: Good Point about querying. Thanks Andy Korneyev.

Comment: This inside a method `XElement Validate(XDocument xml, XName descendantName, XName mandatoryElementName)` with `return id;` instead of `OrdersXml += id;` would probably do a lot for reusability. Then all that is needed would be a `Dictionary<XName, List<XName>>` to store all `descendantName`s and (a list of) their `mandatoryElementName`s.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I see it, but you should use a XSD schema.

```
foreach(var personalData in xdoc.Element("Orders").Descendants()){
      if(personalData.Value == null){
        //error? 
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks greenfeet, but your answer does not help me a lot.

Comment: It would help if you told me why it doesn't help you, because it answers your current question. Maybe update it or specify what you want.